# Find digit in unit place | PHP

Tags: php, find, digit

after a few exercises of php i found two exercises that i got stuck on, though i have give it many tries.

the 1st one :

Write a simple program to print the digit in unit place of a number entered by the user.

input : Enter Number:3457

output 7

```
 <?php 
    $answer=0;
    echo "Enter Number:";
    $number = trim(fgets(STDIN));


     //{Write down your logic here



     //} 
  echo $answer;
  exit;
?>
```

the 2nd one :

Write a program to see whether a number is an even multiple of 3.

input : Enter the number:6

output : yes

input : the number:9

output : no

```
 <?php 
    echo "Enter the Number:";
    $number = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    //{
    //write down your logic here






    //}
  exit;
?>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: we will get certificate instead of you.... is it ok for u ?

Comment: @user1844933 well said!! :)

Answer (score 1):

**here is solution for 1st one:**

```
<?php 
    $answer=0;
   echo "Enter Number:";
   $numbers = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    $number = intval($numbers);
if(is_float($number)){
    list($int, $dec) = explode('.', $number);
    if($number < 0){
    $answer = "-".substr($int, -1);
    }
    else{
        $answer = substr($int, -1);
    }
}

else{
     if($number < 0){
    $answer = "-".substr($number, -1);
    }
    else{
        $answer = substr($number, -1);
    }
}

  echo $answer;
  exit;
?>
```

**solution for 2nd one**

```
<?php 
 echo "Enter the Number:";
$number = trim(fgets(STDIN));
 //{
    //write down your logic here
  $even = $number % 2;                  //to check number is even or not
 if($even == 0){
  $mod = $number % 3;                   //to check whether it is devisible by 3 or not
  if($mod == 0){
      echo "yes";
  }
  else{
      echo "no";
  }
 }
 else{
     echo "no";
 }

    //}
  exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Write a simple program to print the digit in unit place of a number entered by the user.

Assuming the input is type string, you can approach this with character arrays. For example:

```
//We subtract 1 from strlen() because indexes start at 0
echo (string) $number[strlen($number)-1];
```

> Write a program to see whether a number is an even multiple of 3.

We can use the [modulo operator](http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic) for this, and see if we divide by 3 there is a remainder.

```
echo ($number % 3 == 0) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Comment: You're welcome @HamzaCharkaoui `:)`. Please consider closing your question and [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). This will notify other users that your question has been answered and helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Although i still think there is a better way to solve this exercise. I was able to pass it using the following solution

```
<?php 
    $answer=0;
   echo "Enter Number:";

   // Converts the number into a double to cover all input cases
   $number = (double)trim(fgets(STDIN));


     //{Write down your logic here

    // Checks to see if a negetive number was entered
    if ($number <0){

    // Gets the Position of the decimal Point and reduce it by 1 to get
    // the position of the Units place

    $position = strpos($number, ".") - 1;

    // returns the units string and makes it negetive
    $answer = substr ($number,$position,1 ) * -1;
}

// follows the same as above, leaves string positive
else {
        $position = strpos($number, ".") - 1;
     $answer = substr ($number,$position,1 );

}

     //} 
  echo $answer;
  exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

```
<?php 
    $answer=0;
    echo "Enter Number:";
    $number = trim(fgets(STDIN));


    $number = intval($number);
    $answer = substr($number, (-1));
    if($number < 0)
    {
        $answer = $answer * -1;
    }


  echo $answer;
  exit;
?>
```

**Solution 2**

```
<?php 
    echo "Enter the Number:";
    $number = trim(fgets(STDIN));


    $number2 = $number / 3;
    if ($number2 % 2 == 0) 
    {
        echo "yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "no";
    }


  exit;
?>
```